# How can I sort a GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

> SELECT id, user_id FROM orders  GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC

I am trying to get all of the "last" orders users ordered.
The problem with this query is that GROUP BY runs before ORDER BY, so I still get the first order of each user rather than their last.

Is there another way to write this to get the desired result? Do I need to resort to a second query / sub query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want this instead:

```
select max(id), user_id from orders group by user_id
```